# Angular 6 deployed to Firebase fails to load CSS when browsing routes via URL or Refresh

Tags: angular, firebase, routes, firebase-hosting

If you browse [here](https://kerihobo.com) and use my navbar to go to 'tutorials'... everything seems fine... until you try to refresh the page from that point. The page loads, and routing still seems to work... but all the CSS is gone...

I've googled a lot already and the verdict seems to be that simply having the json configured like this should be enough to prevent this issue on Firebase. I can confirm that this issue only happens on Firebase, when I test on localhost I'm able to refresh without any problems.

```json
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "dist/lessons",
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "rewrites": [{
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please replace the link to a screenshot of your firebase.json, with the actual contents of that file. That allow us to see if without clicking, makes it searchable, allows us to copy parts of it, and in genera is a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I can tell you one thing and that's that your css does import something I have no clue what but go to the sources and refresh and check your css file. What I see here amazes me cause your content of main.js is shown inside your css file. Also the css file move from the `./` to `./tutorials`. I doubt this has anything to do with the firebase deployment.

Comment: It wont let me submit an answer here... I had the typical firebase.json stuff that was suggested for angular.... turns out I had carelessly deleted a very important piece of boilerplate html very early on when i was tidying up.... do NOT remove <base href="/"> from your html file in an SPA!!! It works fine now.